# Uniquely identify each element using key and change props to that Element in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have lists of JSON object in a JSON Array. Where each element is uniquely identified with key

JSON Object contains:

> **event_name**
>
> **date_time**

```
{this.props.events.map((event) =>
   (
    <div key={event.event_name}>
        <ul>
          <div><h4>{event.event_name}</h4>
            <div>            //ternary operation next line
            {this.state.mic?<span onClick={()=>this.onMicClickOn(event.event_name)}>
           <MicOn /> </span> :<span onClick={()=>this.onMicClickOff(event.event_name)}>
           <MicOff /> </span>}              
                 </div>
                 </div>
                 <li>{event.date_time}</li></ul>
               </div>
            ))}
```

I have this state

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          mic : false,
        }

      }

onMicClickOff=event =>{
        this.setState({ mic: true });
    }

onMicClickOn =event =>{
    this.setState({ mic : false});
}
```

I want to show the mic off and on only for **event.event_name specific**.
Currently what is happening is I am displaying mic-on and mic-off on each event of JSON object rather the **clicked object**. Rather only to the **unique key**.

I know the problem that mic state is globally declared and state for all. But is there something I could do to append event_name to mic state to make it unique.

Comment: Is it useful if you add one more property to your global state object along side "mic" property like this.state = {
mic : false, event: ''  } and then you can set this.state.event with the name you are passing to click handlers and in your html side you can check along side this.state.mic && this.state.event==event.name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a state property to keep each individual `event`s on/off position rather than keeping a generic one.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    micStates: {}
  };

  handleMicState = id =>
    this.setState(current => ({
      micStates: { ...current.micStates, [id]: !current.micStates[id] }
    }));

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.events.map(event => (
          <div key={event.event_name}>
            <ul>
              <div>
                <h4>{event.event_name}</h4>
                <div>
                  {this.state.micStates[event.id] ? (
                    <span onClick={() => this.handleMicState(event.id)}>
                      <p>On</p>{" "}
                    </span>
                  ) : (
                    <span onClick={() => this.handleMicState(event.id)}>
                      <p>Off</p>{" "}
                    </span>
                  )}
                </div>
              </div>
              <li>{event.date_time}</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const events = [
  { id: 1, event_name: "foo", date_time: 12345 },
  { id: 2, event_name: "bar", date_time: 67890 },
  { id: 3, event_name: "baz", date_time: 12345 }
];
ReactDOM.render(<App events={events} />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

The crucial part is here:

```
handleMicState = id =>
    this.setState(current => ({
      micStates: { ...current.micStates, [id]: !current.micStates[id] }
}));
```

There are two things going on here.

First, we are using a function for `setState` rather than directly using an object. This is because we are using a previous state property to set our new state. This is the suggested way of doing a `setState` if our new state is depending on the old one because `setState` is asynchronous.

Second, we are changing the `event` `id`s as false/true. In the first render nothing is in `micStates` so every mic event is off. With the first click it goes like this for the first event:

```
micStates: { 1: true }
```

and so on...

```
micStates: { 1: true, 2: false, 3: true } // etc.
```

This is [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

```
...current.micStates
```

This is [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names).

```
[id]: !current.micStates[id]
```

Maybe slightly a better approach:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    micStates: {}
  };

  handleMicState = id =>
    this.setState(current => ({
      micStates: { ...current.micStates, [id]: !current.micStates[id] }
    }));

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.events.map(event => (
          <Event
            micState={this.state.micStates[event.id]}
            event={event}
            onMicState={this.handleMicState}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Event = ({ event, onMicState, micState }) => {
  const handleClick = () => onMicState(event.id);
  return (
    <div key={event.event_name}>
      <ul>
        <div>
          <h4>{event.event_name}</h4>
          <div>
            {micState ? (
              <span onClick={handleClick}>
                <p>On</p>{" "}
              </span>
            ) : (
              <span onClick={handleClick}>
                <p>Off</p>{" "}
              </span>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
        <li>{event.date_time}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

const events = [
  { id: 1, event_name: "foo", date_time: 12345 },
  { id: 2, event_name: "bar", date_time: 67890 },
  { id: 3, event_name: "baz", date_time: 12345 }
];
ReactDOM.render(<App events={events} />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: what this line does `this.setState(current => ({
      micStates: { ...current.micStates, [id]: !current.micStates[id] }
    }))` ?

Comment: @Plootus, I've added some explanations.

Comment: can you please tell what is current here and also three dots before current `...current.micStates`

Comment: `current` is just a name for the current state. You can use any name for it. Dots are spread syntax. You can find the documentation link in my explanation.

Comment: but problem is I want to call **startRecord** method when `<MicOn />` tag is visible where the ternary operation is executed how do I check this with micStates with handleMicState method?

Comment: I have askied another question related to this thing ......https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53610608/record-audio-one-at-a-time-and-stop-to-save-in-reactjs

Comment: Can you please reply to this question?

Answer (score 1):

U can also do with this solution hope this will be helpfull for u.

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          mics :{},
        }
     }

     handleMics = name =>{
        let {mics}=this.state;
        mics[name]=mics[name]? false : true;
        this.setState({ mics });
     }

     {this.props.events.map((event) =>
       (
        <div key={event.event_name}>
            <ul>
              <div><h4>{event.event_name}</h4>
                <div>            //ternary operation next line
                {this.state.mics[event.event_name]?
                     <span onClick={()=>this.handleMics(event.event_name)}>
                         <MicOn /> 
                    </span> :
                    <span onClick={()=>this.handleMics(event.event_name)}> 
                       <MicOff />
                    </span>}              
                   </div>
                  </div>
               <li>{event.date_time}</li></ul>
           </div>
         ))
      }
```

Comment: what I want is to call some method like startRecord, stopRecord, deleteRecord  which will at stopRecord will send the current event means event_name, date_time and recording file to the method saveRecord

Comment: So please edit ur question what want to do clarify that

Comment: I have askied another question related to this thing ......https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53610608/record-audio-one-at-a-time-and-stop-to-save-in-reactjs

Comment: can you please reply to the above question?